# Laravel 4 Undefined Index DATE

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4.

I have an array I have passed to a view.
I kept getting the error Undefined index DATE.

I ran the command below just to makes sure that it was an array being received. The output is:

```
Command:
var_dump($theArray)
Output:

array (size=1)
0 => 
array (size=6)
  'id' => int 30
  'EMP_ID' => string 'RD-NRB-032' (length=10)
  'DATE' => string '2014-01-29' (length=10)
  'BRANCH' => null
  'MONTH' => null
  'YEAR' => null
```

I was trying to access the

```
$theArray['DATE']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your output, it is a multidimensional array and you're missing the first key.  Try this:

```
$theArray[0]['DATE']
```